# Using ng-repeat inside a ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't seem to dynamically update my ui-view with ng-repeat. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? The reason I say this is because if I place any static objects in the intro.html it gets displayed..

Thanks for the help in advance,

> JS

```
  }).state('app.register', {
        url: '/register',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'app/register/register.html',
                controller: 'RegisterController'
            }
        }
    }).state('app.register.intro', {
        url: '/intro',
        templateUrl: 'app/register/intro.html'
```

> register.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Register">

      <ion-content class="has-header">
        <ui-view>
        </ui-view>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

> intro.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="value in items">
         value
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is your 'intro.html' file is missing a closing '>' tag for your first div.

Comment: Good catch, I forgot to include that when I was scrubbing the files. However its not actually like that in my application.

Comment: Is 'Items' in 'RegisterController'?  I would try to add a RegisterController inside your intro state to see if that works.